# Problems in displaying the values of combobox in the grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to print the value of combobox in Ext.grid.Panel (Extjs 6).

I do this:

```
....

{
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        text: 'Контрагент',
        dataIndex: 'contragent',
        editor: {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('ContrAgents'),
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'id'
            },
            renderer: function(val){
            myStore = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('ContrAgents');

                index = myStore.findExact('contragent',val);
                console.log(index);
                if (index != -1){
                    rs = myStore.getAt(index).data;
                    return rs.display;
                }
            }
},

....
```

index for each record is always with the value -1, but in each record the value of this combobox is set.

I noticed that when I get the store:

```
myStore = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup ('ContrAgents');
console.log(myStore);
```

In the console, I see:

```
constructor {removed: Array(0), isInitializing: false,....
```

Why can not the store be initialized?

Comment: Please share example with fiddel

Comment: I understand that the problem is in index =myStore.findExact ('contragent', val);
but I do not understand why. In myStore, I definitely have an object

Comment: the val in above code gives the object with both display_field and value_field
console log the val 
`index = myStore.findExact('contragent',val.name);`
this might work

Comment: Make sure that your store is loaded before you are using `findExact` method on it.

Comment: @Nishant Bajracharya In the value "val" there are id of the selected values ​​of the combobox

Comment: @Rohit Sharma I'm sure the store is first loaded

Comment: @Ambasador so can you please create a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) to describe your issue.

Comment: I made a change to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "store:" field you can just type in the ID of the store and then when you are refering to a store with .lookup(), you have to be sure the store is loaded before.

```
this.getStore().load();
```

After that you can go on with your .findExact(parms..);
Looks fine :)

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me